# AnyLogic, Agent Movement to multiple locations and returning to original location

Tags: java, anylogic

How can I move an agent Truck from one place to multiple places one by one and then return to original place?

What should I use: Process modelling or statechart to approach?

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so users can see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

both are possible. If you select Process modelling then your truck should loop through moveTo block for every new destination. Use selectOutput to terminate the loop.
If statechart: again loop but this time between two states: say "inDestination" and "goingToNextDestination".

I both cases you need to take care about some data structure that will store a list of unvisited locations.

Hope that helps, otherwise let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will give it a try

Comment: Actually, the select output will split the orders but I want the order to be same. I want a truck located at location A moves to location B and then to location C and then return to the location A.

Comment: selectOutput is not splitting an order. It is just a fork - based on some condition (i.e. have i visited all locations already?) process flows to one or another branch.